# Can I backup all files, settings, apps, etc. for restoration after reinstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, backup, encryption

I have a new laptop, and it took quite a few tweaks to get Ubuntu running properly.

Unfortunately I just found out that I need to fully encrypt my hard drive, as I use my computer for work.

In the past when I've reinstalled Ubuntu I've just backed up all of my music, docs, pictures and reinstalled Ubuntu without any problems. However, this time around I really don't want to lose everything I set up as it was truly a pain to get running.

So, if I use Backup or Aptik, will that fully restore all of my settings after reinstalling Ubuntu and encrypting my computer?

Thanks!

Comment: Backup will save your files/data - assuming you've pointed to all the files/folders you want saved.  Aptik saves a list of all the applications and ppas you have installed, allowing you to reinstall them easily on a new / reborn system.  The two apps are complementary but do different things.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution is to move all your /home to another partition like explained here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

After that reinstall your System. You will touch the partition / but not the /home partition.

After installation, following the same tutorial:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
see the paragraph "Moving /home into /old_home"

You can move your home to your old_home.

I did it in my last work and y recovery information, schema_databases, emails an account from Thundebird, svn properties, and a lot of more thinks.

I hope it can help you!

Comment: Have you tried it? Are you in some trouble?  tell me know if you could do this. And rating.